# Unable to remove -- Logical volume in use

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm currently experiencing a problem where I cannot delete an lvm snapshot. The snapshot is not mounted nor is it ever mounted although its origin volume is. The command and response I'm getting is as

```
#: lvremove -f lvs/lv0_snapshot
Logical volume lvs/lv0_snaphot in use.
```

`df | grep lvs/lv0_snapshot` and `mount | grep lvs/lv0_snapshot` return nothing which makes sense because I never mount it.

Does anyone know operations that would cause a logical volume, specifically a snapshot to be considered "in use"?

Comment: try using `lsof` maybe to see if anything is using it?

Comment: @Zoredache that gets me 
`COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`
`grub-moun 15280 root    3r   BLK  253,2 0t15302656  400 /dev/lvs/../dm-2`

Comment: What is `grub-moun`?

Comment: Well I would guess it is a truncated output and it is actually grub-mount.  The man page says that is something for exporting the grub fs via FUSE?  I never really seen or used that though.  So you may need to consult Google or wait for someone else.

Comment: I'll look into it this is odd, I never explicitly invoke `grub-mount` which makes me think this must be an intermittent bug

Comment: @Zoredache ty nonetheless for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @Zoredache suggested `lsof` turned up a process referencing the snapshot.

It turns out that grub runs a program called `os-prober` it's purpose is to add OS's to the Grub menu, so what I think is happening is it's seeing my snapshot in /dev/mapper and mounting the device to ensure it's a mountable filesystem and something is happening to keep it from unmounting the filesystem. Since it doesn't get unmounted the lvm rationally refuses to let you delete the partition.

You can apparently disable the `os-prober` from running by setting `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` in the `etc/default/grub` file.

If you simply want to be able to remove your logical volume you can run `findmnt | grep <lv-name>` and then run `umount` on the directory it returns. You should be able to remove the LV after that.

Comment: I found a mounted root like this, unmounted it, but it still says `Logical volume mint-vg1/root in use.` when trying to turn off the logical. Nothing is using this disk.

Comment: this answer was very useful, two things which helped me as well:
1. filter `htop` for the snapshot name
2. check `/dev/mapper` for the `dm-x` allocation
(Since `lsof`, `mount` and `findmnt` didn't reveal it otherwise in my case.)